# Downloading all ctrl alt del webcomics using terminal

Tags: python, download, web-scraping

I've tried using the following commands to download the ctrl alt del comics.

```
$ for filename in $(seq 20021023 20100503); do wget http://www.ctrlaltdel-online.com/comics/"$filename".jpg; done
```

I get the following error code, `bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'do'`

I've also tried using cURL, using this command,

```
curl http://ctrlaltdel-online.com/comics[20021023..20100503].jpg
```

I get the following error code, `curl: (3) [globbing] error: bad range specification after pos 37`

What's wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You are going to end up grabbing a *lot* of 404 pages like that.

Comment: FWIW, I was able to run your script.  Although `seq` is displaying the numbers in exponential form.  I'd suggest writing a quick python script using datetime to generate your numbers, then looping over it with wget (or using python's url getter).

Comment: I'm guessing Tim Buckley wouldn't be pleased with such an effort, in fact, he'd probably rather sell you a book what with him being the copyright holder and such.

Answer (score 2):

As msw pointed out, crawling a site could be either illegal, unethical, irritating to the author, or perfectly fine.  Please use your scripting powers responsibly and for Good (tm). Asking permission would certainly be a nice thing to do.

Note that the ctrlaltdel-online.com web server seems to return HTTP 403 forbidden to wget with the normal wget User-Agent string. Emulating something Firefox-ish seems to bypass that (although I bet they are just explicitly denying wget, which indicates they most likely forbid this type of access).

```
USERAGENT='Mozilla/5.0 Firefox/3.6.3'
for DAYS in $(seq 365)
do
    NEXT=`date -d "${DAYS} days ago" +%Y%m%d`
    wget -U "${USERAGENT}" "http://www.cad-comic.com/comics/cad/${NEXT}.jpg"
done
```

Replace 365 with a larger number to go back more than a year.  The wget output might be annoying, so you can pass it -q to make it quiet.

Answer (score 0):

i was writing the same script. Here it is.

```
import sys
import re
import urllib
import os
import ctypes
from urllib import FancyURLopener

class MyOpener(FancyURLopener):
    version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it;rv:1.8.1.11)Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11'


def getlinks(add,m,opener):
    ufile=opener.open(add)
    html=ufile.read()
    dates=re.findall('href="/cad/(\d+)">',html)
    links=[]
    for date in dates:
            if date[4:6]==m:
            links.append('http://www.cad-comic.com/cad/'+date)
    links.reverse()
    print 'Total {} comics found.'.format(len(links))
    #print len(links)
    return links

def getstriplink(link,opener):
    ufile=opener.open(link)
    html=ufile.read()
    url=re.search('img src="(.+)" alt="(.+)" title=',html)
    date=link[-8:]
    return(url.group(1),url.group(2),date)



def main():
    y=raw_input('Enter year 2002 - current(yyyy) ')
    m=raw_input('Enter month(only months 12,11 and 10 for 2002)(mm) ')
    add='http://www.cad-comic.com/cad/archive/'+y
    opener=MyOpener()
    links=getlinks(add,m,opener)
    f=open('/media/aux1/pythonary/cad'+str(y)+str(m)+'.html','w')
    print 'downloading'
    for link in links:
        url=getstriplink(link,opener)
        #date=url[0][-8:]
        date=url[2]
        opener.retrieve(url[0],'/media/aux1/pythonary/getcad_files/strip'+date)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        print'.',
        f.write('<h2>'+url[1]+' '+date+'</h2>'+'<p><img src="getcad_files/strip'+date+'"/></p>')

    f.close()




if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```